# Validating age to be greater than 18, counting from today's date

Tags: lotus-domino

I have a lotus application which contains a field where employee have to enter thier date of birth... I want to validate that the employee age should be greater than 18yrs calculating from current date..
How can I do that???

I did

```
diff :=@Year(@Today)-@Year(@ThisValue);
@If(@ThisValue = ""; @Return("Please enter 'Date of Birth'."); @ThisValue != "" & @Date(@ThisValue) > @Date(@Today); @Return("'Date of Birth' should not be greater than 'Today Date'."); diff <18; @Return("'Age' cannot be less than 18yrs."); @Success)
```

But this only calculates the current year....how do i do calculating the current date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function `@Adjust( dateToAdjust ; years ; months ; days ; hours ; minutes ; seconds ; [DST] )`

```
@Adjust(@Now;-18;0;0;0;0;0)
```

And compare it to the birthdate of the employee